# net-snmp random timeout walking nsExtendOutput1Table

Tags: linux, snmp

Good day to you.

I have net-snmp-5.4.2.1-r1 on recent gentoo host, there's an extension to snmpd configuration, like :

```
   exec dashboard-hlpdesk-login /opt/server/bin/hlpdesk-login.sh
   exec dashboard-radius-login /opt/server/bin/radius-login.sh
```

Fetching values by MIB or OID is fine except when I run

```
snmpwalk  -v2c -c public localhost NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Table
Timeout: No Response from localhost
```

That timeout seems random.

And that also affects fetching single extended oids either with snmpget or snmpwalk, fetching freezes for several seconds and then works again.

P.S. I've also tried it on recent Debian Squeeze, same.

Comment: One of extend cmds take 1-5sec to complete.

Answer (score 0):

By default the timeout for snmpwalk is really really short(I've seen implementations where it is set to 300ms by default).  Try:

```
# snmpwalk -t 20 ...
```

(or whatever the timeout value is for the version of snmpwalk you are using)